# VS Code - Use rails debugger on ubuntu subsystem for windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, windows, visual-studio-code

I have succesfully installed rvm, ruby and rails on the ubuntu subsystem on windows 10.

Now I'm trying to use the debugger on vs code for windows, but I can't find a way to do so. On my linux machine I use:

```
{
  "name": "Rails server",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/bundle",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true,
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "args": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

I tried pointing the path to the linux subsystem (%localappdata%\Lxss\home\user\.rvm...) but it doesn't work, as windows doesn't see this path.

Has anyone been able to succesfully use rdebug on linux subsytem?

Comment: Are you sure you need it? I'd recommend using the `pry` gem if you're just looking for breakpoints

Comment: I find that debugging through VS Code is much better than using pry, but thanks for the suggestion!